# Process flat file only if it does not has junk data in for each loop

Tags: ssis, foreach-loop-container

I have a for each loop container which is processing flat files. A few of the files may have junk data. I want to ignore those files and process the other files without package failure.

Comment: So what's the question here? How to continue execution when your package fails due to malformed data documents?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I have done in the past is to use a **flatfile destination** in the `foreachloop` container as an error output, so that any bad data in my sourcefile is sent there and the package does not fail.

What you do is to insert the `flatfile destination` into the `forechloop` and connect it to flatfile source.

After you have done this edit the `Flatfile destination` and point it to the `error.txt` and map the columns to error output columns. This is what works for me to get rid of bad data.